# IIS won't install

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I need to install IIS on my machine but I keep the following error:
[image: Error message showing "An error has occurred. Not all of the features were successfully changed."]

After closing the message I can open inetmgr but it is removed after reboot.
I've tried the following:

- Checking for windows updates
- Attempting to search for fails in the log, none found
- Attempting to uninstall IIS, not found in "Uninstall or change a
  program" but is shown as installed in Web Platform Installer
- Changing Visual studio install and installing all features

[Here](http://pastebin.com/vH6fHGLK) is my IIS7.log file from C:\Windows

**Update**
I fixed this by installing old versions of .net

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/2012/07/if-you-cannot-installuninstall-iis-7-part-ii/

Comment: Vista or Windows Server 2008?

Comment: @KornMuffin Windows 7